# Using styled-components results in `cannot read withConfig of undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, styled-components

When attempting to transpile the `Spacing.js` file, it results in an undefined import even when `styled-components` was seemingly being imported and used (in the same way) successfully in other files. Even when removing the styled-components babel plugin, a similar error occurs.

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react-native"],
  "plugins": [
    ["styled-components", { "displayName": true }],
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "react-native-web",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-inline-elements",
        "transform-react-constant-elements"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`Spacing.js` - Code before transpilation

```
import React, { Component, Node } from "React";
import styled from "styled-components";

type Props = {
  size: string,
  color: string,
  fullWidth?: boolean
};

class SpacingComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render(): Node {
    const { size, color, fullWidth = false } = this.props;
    return <Spacing size={size} color={color} fullWidth={fullWidth} />;
  }
}

const Spacing = styled.View`
  height: ${props => props.size}px;
  background-color: ${props => props.color || "transparent"};
  width: ${props => {
    return props.fullwidth ? "100%" : props.size + "px";
  }};
`;

export default SpacingComponent;
```

1. Generated code for importing and resolving `styled-components`

[image]

2. Generated code for using the `styled-components` library (v3.2.5)

[image]

3. The resulting error

[image]

Another example can be seen when removing the `styled-components` babel plugin from the babelrc, thus the withConfig is not added.

1. Generated error with no `styled-components` babel plugin

[image]

2. Generated code making this error

[image]

---

Is babel or webpack adding `.default` when it doesn't need to, if so, how could I investigate why?

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but I'd recommend switching to the [env preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) instead of es2015, for reasons described on the linked page

Comment: I was using env originally and switched to es2015 to see if my env config was causing the error, but it wasn't. Thanks for reminding me to switch back

Answer (score 7):

try doing `styled(View)` instead of `styled.View`

Comment: it says View doesn't exist, as it's now a variable rather than an attribute... Whoever upvoted this please lend us a hand, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is going to be helpful to anyone but for me the same error was triggered like this `style.something` and fixed using an html element eg `style.span`